# How to set a preference enable false or true programatically?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferencescreen

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="User Profile">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="email"
        app:title="Display Email ID"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_memory_black_24dp"
        app:enabled="false"
        />
```

I want to handle it at run time programmatically.

getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("email").setEnabled(false);

this is not working for API 29.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

What do you mean by API 29?

Comment: then use getPreferenceManager().findPreference("email").setEnabled(false); refer this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceGroup#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)